# C# smtp.google.com could not be resolved

Tags: c#, email

Following code used to work but suddenly refuses to work.

```
private static void SendMail()
{
    try
    {
        var mail = new MailMessage();
        var smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.google.com", 587);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("catthoor.jc@gmail.com", "Jasper.Kattoor");
        mail.To.Add("YYYY");
        mail.Subject = "sup";
        mail.Body = "sup";
        smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("catthoor.jc@gmail.com", "XXXX");
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'smtp.google.com'

I've also tried using hotmail instead of gmail, same error.
I can still send mails manually though.
Why would this error suddenly occur? Yesterday there were no problems with this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That remote host name is wrong, it should be:

```
smtp.gmail.com
```

Read all about it: [Send Email from Yahoo!, GMail, Hotmail (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520998/Send-Email-from-Yahoo-GMail-Hotmail-Csharp)

**Updates**: You can also ping the host name to check if it exists using command prompt

[image]

Comment: Oh god how could I not have seen this. Thank you. Still wondering what happened since it used to work..

Comment: The smallest bugs causes the biggest headaches :)

Comment: i don't have both `smtp.gmail.com ` and `smtp.google.com` what should i do now? Same error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my case I wasn't just connected to the internet.
After I connected the problem was gone.

Comment: This should be a comment.